# How should a teenage girl get ready for a job hunt?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, hiring-process, stress, pressure

I am considering doing a physical job hunt sometime today (Saturday, 6/11/16), and I am wondering if maybe I need to up my game in terms of my looks?    And being as I have no real experience or marketable job skills, how should I sell my self?

Comment: What industry are you looking for a job in? This will wildly change the expected norms.

Comment: I also think that you are worrying too much about minor details. Nobody is going to care about the minor details in beauty unless you're looking for a job in that specific industry, and even then I have doubts that ponytail vs no ponytail would make a difference.

Comment: @Paparazzi A troll or just someone who's rather juvenile and unfamiliar with adult/professional behaviour. The former should be ignored, the latter should be helped. I'm inclined to believe this is on the level. The core question is worth answering in my opinion, but the entire rambling post after that is besides the point.

Comment: I am just nervous is all, okay? And, yes, I am literally juvenile. I am a teenager. As I have mentioned before. And I have never had a real job in my life, which is a problem. I just feel like nobody really likes me, and like I'll never be good enough. Would it help if I told you that my disability is autism and that I have a long history of being treated badly by a variety of people? Or would that make me seem even more like a troll? Sorry for upsetting everyone, I'll just shut up now.

Comment: @JobSeakernumber1000 you had me going at thinking you were a troll haha (My apologies)! I have a friend with autism and he has worked at surpermarkets (restocking shelves, unloading the trucks, etc) even after a while he worked the cash register and now he works at a warehouse. Maybe start looking into those areas where teens usually work or get hired quicker (heck try the local mc donalds).

Comment: You might get better answers if you tell us what kind of job you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

Relax. 98% of what an employer cares about is whether you can do the job well. Going in grungy might cost you the job, but going in dressed as you would for dealing with any other adult -- not high fashion, but looking clean, non-challenging, and respectable -- is really all that's needed unless you are trying for a job in an extremely high-fashion place.

Basically, just go in clothes that don't force then to notice the clothes, and you'll be fine. No evening gowns, no rude t-shirts, no torn jeans unless that's the style they sell. Present yourself as the kind of store employee you would be comfortable asking advice from. That really is most of what they are looking for.

Comment: The first word sums up the best strategy, relax.

Answer (score 6):

As a teenager you need to worry about people taking you seriously. Dress "sensibly" nothing over the top, you don't need lots of make up etc.  Try not to wear tennis shoes or exercise clothes.  If it's notAbercrombie & Fitch or whatever then how you look will not be the most important thing.

You will look professional and serious about it than if you bring around copies of your CV printed out. (Very old school).  Have a firm handshake and make eye contact.  Best of luck.

Comment: Even for Abercrombie & Fitch you still don't interview in tennis shoes and exercise clothes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your physical appearance (how your face/body looks) is hugely important. No one expects teenagers to be great beauties, and if they do it might be better not applying for those places.

As long as you are wearing clothes and makeup that would be appropriate for the workplace you are applying for that is what is most important.

It might be a good idea to skip the dangly earrings or go for something smaller.

As @user26491 mentions a professional manner will is important.